# MariaDB architecture question for maximum write speed. If there is only one DB server, and only one DB, 1 table or split into 2 for max writing speed?

Tags: mariadb

MariaDB 10.11 database architecture question for maximum write speed. Write speeds need to be about 250-300 per second in a) (1) billion row partitioned table or b) (2) billion row partitioned tables. If there is only one DB server, and only one DB, and if the data to be written into the db are 2 BIGINTS a DATETIME(3) and 3 VARCHAR: VARCHAR(64), VARCHAR(500) and VARCHAR(128); wouldn't one table always allow faster write rates than splitting the tables into 2: one with 2 BIGINTS and teh VARCHAR(500) and the other with the 2 lesser VARCHAR , the DATETIME(3) and two BIGINTS, one of which is from the first table?

Is there any reason or set of circumstances which would make the two table approach allow for faster write speeds, given the client requirements, below? (I have already informed the client that I will almost certainly need to use temporary or staging tables to insert the data that quickyl, especially if I cant batch it and do group inserts).

These are the client requirements: No Master-Replica allowed, no REDIS layer allowed, would prefer NOT to have any temporary or staging tables, would rather NOT group inserts/writes.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you rather not group writes?

Comment: The server does not write into tables itself. It tells to OS file requestor - write these bytes to this position in this file. The requestor then sends the commands to the disk subsystem - write these bytes to these sectors. The amount of files in the data directory is low - so there is no difference.

Comment: It's the client who would rather not group or batch writes - because then they would have to hire a python or perl or C++ scripter to write a script, right? Maria DB doesn't offer this functionality, does it?

Comment: It's hard for me to believe that there isn't a considerable increase in efficiency and performance, thus maximum write rates per second, in one table versus two.  This is my question - isn't it better to just add columns to a billion row table, even if they are VARCHAR than to have to write an equalnumber of rows in a second table?

Comment: "would prefer NOT to have any temporary or staging tables, would rather NOT group inserts/writes." -- Well, that eliminates the best solutions!

Comment: Please give more details -- `SHOW CREATE TABLE` with non-obscured column names so that I have a clue of the type of data (order processing, weather data, vehicle tracking, whatever).  I may have an idea that is not as drastic as staging/batching.

Comment: Two tables is unlikely to help; won't that mess up the other code worse than staging/batching would??

Comment: What indexes on the table?  They may be helping or hurting; need the CREATE TABLE.

Comment: Elaborate on why you consider adding a column -- that solves different issues than adding another table.

Comment: You mentioned "partitioned", but it is unclear whether the table _is_ partitioned or you are asking _whether_ partitioning would help.  (It probably will not help, but need to see CREATE TABLE both before and after tentative partitioning.

Comment: "lesser VARCHAR" -- Do you mean "smaller" ("shorter strings")?  Or "often NULL"?

Comment: My discussion on [_high-speed ingestion_](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table)

Comment: Anyway, 300/sec is quite possible with SSD drives of today; are you actually having a problem?

Comment: Here is the current working SHOW CREATE for the two DB's: https://gist.github.com/EdNett/27f649136c2dac3cc143ea16d9f0d4af     and I will post my merged and improved SHOW CREATE in a few hours, or tomorrow. I am working on it now and have done a good deal of normalization and VARCHAR and other datatype size reduction .

Comment: Info about the database is here:  https://gist.github.com/EdNett/97aa3338957794891ee8230a154898ec

Comment: My "improved" 1.5 billion + row CREATE TABLE is here:

Comment: My "improved" 1.5 billion + row CREATE TABLE is here: https://gist.github.com/EdNett/937f4f6d145693936df56f2498da53dd      I will have to add foreign keys and link it to ST_STEP_ID in T_TEST_STEP. Do you see how I have included the actual name of the column "ST_STEP_ID" from the "T_TEST_STEP" table rather than prefacing it with the table name "Measurement" as in "Measurement_ST_STEP_ID" as teh oracle db creator did - isn't my way best practice ?

Comment: And Rick, thanks for the advice - I saw that you don't recommend more than 50 partitions, but isn't 92 daily better than 4 monthly, so that I won't need two temp tables for partition pruing - so that the REORGANIZE PARTITION isn't too slow. In the current Oracle architecture they have 2 temp tables to hold incomind data while the partitions are being renamed. Do you think I can avoid doing the same sith daily partitions in Maria DB 10.11?

Answer (score 0):

> It's the client who would rather not group or batch writes...Maria DB doesn't offer this functionality, does it?

Huh?...you can insert multiple rows at the same time, either in a single table or for multiple tables. Here's [some examples](https://www.mariadbtutorial.com/mariadb-basics/mariadb-insert-multiple-rows/) on doing it with just pure SQL.

> It's hard for me to believe that there isn't a considerable increase in efficiency and performance, thus maximum write rates per second, in one table versus two.

Why would you think that?...At the end of the day 100 GB of data is 100 GB of data. The hardware doesn't care if you split it up into two tables or one, it still needs to write the same amount of data to disk.

And actually, at the software layer in the database, two tables *can* be faster as opposed to one, for reduced locking contention reasons in the context of concurrency, for certain scenarios.

What I mean by that is if your single table is locked frequently, e.g. from a specific column being read from often, then the `INSERT` statement to write to it could be blocked waiting for the read(s) to finish. All of the data being inserted into this single table would have to wait to be written. In the scenario where there's two tables, then at least all of the data that gets written to the second table won't have to necessarily wait for the read(s) on the column from the first table to finish. That *half* of the data can be written immediately. This, of course, assumes the data can be broken up and written in a non-transactional way.

So to recap, from a hardware write speed perspective it doesn't matter (like Akina's comments point out). From a software architectural perspective, there are specific cases where writing to multiple tables are actually faster.

As an aside, you'll probably find the docs on [How to Quickly Insert Data Into MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-quickly-insert-data-into-mariadb/) to be of use.

Comment: OK, So I guess I wasn't very clear. Of course I know that multiple rows can be inserted in 1 SQL insert. The data coming in is one set of data at a time, so I would have to write a script which writes 10 to 100 lines of data to a file, and then use LOAD DATA INFILE to insert the data into the db table. I don't write those kinds of scripts, so someone would need to be hired, etc.  I don't agree with your analysis. This data is not "transactional" in the sense of monetary transactions, and maintaining the perfect chronological order of data line or row into the db table is not important

Comment: "*I don't agree with your analysis.*" - Interesting statement without any reasoning. Not even sure what part of my answer you're referring to?

Comment: "*Of course I know that multiple rows can be inserted in 1 SQL insert. The data coming in is one set of data at a time, so I would have to write a script which writes 10 to 100 lines of data to a file, and then use LOAD DATA INFILE to insert the data into the db table.*" - What does loading 1 row of data vs multiple rows of data at a time have to do with this? Why even write a script for the data to a file as opposed to using SQL to directly insert it? If you're saying because it's a huge amount of data being provided then don't you have to write a script even just for pulling 1 row at a time?

Comment: @EdNett Forgot to tag you. Please see my previous comments / questions.

Comment: "Lock contention" -- This implies multiple processes are doing inserts.  @EdNett - Is Your inserting' single-threaded or not?

Comment: One of those links suggests disabling keys -- don't do that if the 250-300/sec rows are coming in "continually".  The suggestion applies only to _large_ batches of rows being inserted all at once. @EdNett

Comment: I am building the combined DB - so what do you recommend, inserting single threaded or not ?